# Text widget always stays on top and doesn't disappear as I scroll

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-animation, flutter-test

My text widget "More" always stays on top even though I scroll down, I'm not finding the root of this issue,

I've tried wrapping it in a SingleChildScrollView widget but still nothing has changed, are there any  arguments for the Text widget that allows it to scroll as the user scrolls that I don't know of? Or is it something else entirely?

Code:

```
class MorePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MorePageState createState() => _MorePageState();
}

class _MorePageState extends State<MorePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: white,
      body: Stack(
        // YESSSS
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
            SizedBox(height: 45.0),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: kDefaultPaddin),
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 25,
              child: Text(
                "MORE",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: black,
                    fontFamily: "Raleway",
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                    fontSize: 25),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),),
          ]),
          Container(
            // YESSSS
            child: getBody(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Stack(), Stack will overlay children on top of others.

Answer (score 0):

while using `Stack` wrap with fixed-Sized Widget, It can be just `Container()`, also while using Stack, use Aligning widgets as child => `Center`, `Align`, `Positioned`, else  use stack `fit` property,

to know more about `Stack` Visit https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MorePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MorePageState createState() => _MorePageState();
}

class _MorePageState extends State<MorePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          child: Stack(
            // YESSSS
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
                SizedBox(height: 45.0),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 22),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 25,
                    child: Text(
                      "MORE",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontFamily: "Raleway",
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                          fontSize: 25),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ]),
              Center(
                child: Container(
                    color: Colors.amber,
                    // YESSSS
                    height: 1333,
                    child: Text("Body")
                    // getBody(),
                    ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```